# ¿Cómo cerrar la sesión al cerrar el navegador usando CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

En `CI2` había una opción que te permitía configurar el cierre de sesión automático al cerrar el navegador.

En `CI3` supuestamente la solución el colocar en `0` a `$config['sess_expiration'];` pero he probado y nada.

Si alguien ya encontró la solución, agradecería mucho lo comparta.

Answer (score 2):

En CI 2 tenias: `$config['sess_expire_on_close']`, pero detectar cuando el usuario cierra la pestaña/ventana no siempre funcionaba.

Puedes usar JavaScript, con los eventos: `onunload` o `onbeforeunload` y cargar una página que contenga un $`this->session->sess_destroy();` pero toma en cuenta que el evento saltará cuando pases a otro enlace de la misma página, en general lo normal es tener una sesión que dure `x` minutos e ir revisando si el usuario tiene actividad en el sitio para renovarla.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación, es como mencionas, setear `sess_expiration` en `0`. Mira: [Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences)

También encontré esto en SO:

> Técnicamente no se puede destruir la sesión cuando se cierra el navegador . Sólo se puede decir que el navegador descarta la cookie de sesión después de que se cerró , pero la misma sesión es aún utilizable en el lado del servidor.
>   La sesión se elimina más tarde por el recolector de basura.

[Pregunta SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388856/how-to-destroy-session-with-browser-closing-in-codeigniter-3)

Answer (score 0):

- Haz que dure la sesión por poco tiempo por ejemplo 5 minutos como los bancos
- O mediante el uso de [javascrpt](/questions/tagged/javascrpt) que te aparezca un *dialog* cuando cierras la pestaña o el navegador, el típico que dice desea salir y no guardar los cambios cuando estas en un *form*.